# Subset the Orginal dataframe with different combinations of 2 factor variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 11 columns and 18350 observations which has a variable company and region. There are 9 companies(company-0) spread across 5 regions(region-0 to region-5) and not all companies are present at all regions. I want to create a seperate dataframe for each combination of company and region.You can see like this-
company0-region1,
company0-region10,
company0-region7,
company1-region5,
company2-region0,
company3-region2,
company4-region3,
company5-region7,
company6-region6,
company8-region9,
company9-region8

Thus I need 11 different dataframes in R.No other combinations are possible 
Any other approach would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

I used split function to get a list-

```
p<-split(tsog1,list(tsog1$company),drop=TRUE)
```

Now I have a list of dataframes and I can't convert the each element of that list into an individual dataframe.

I tried using loops too, but can't get a unique named dataframe.

```
v<-c(1:9)
p<-levels(tsog1$company)
for (x in v)
{
  x.tsog1<-subset(tsog1,tsog1$company==p[x])
}
```

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P842p.png)

Comment: Can you add a reproducible data here for us to help you?  Please add `dput(data)` output in your question.

Comment: hey!! I am new to stack, I wanted to add the dataset, But I wonder how to do that??

Comment: Once you read in the data in your `R` environment, run `dput(head(data))`, then paste the output here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column for the region company combination and split by that column.

For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create a df with 9 regions, 6 companies, and some dummy observations (3 per case)
df <- expand.grid(region = 0:8, company = 0:5, dummy = 1:3 ) %>% 
  mutate(x = round(rnorm((54*3)),2)) %>% 
  select(-dummy) %>% as_tibble()

# Create the column to split, and split.
df %>% 
  mutate(region_company = paste(region,company, sep = '_')) %>% 
  split(., .$region_company)
```

Now, what to do once you have the list of data frames, depends on your next steps. If you want to for example, save them, you can do `walk` or `lapply`.

For saving:

```r
df_list <- df %>% 
  mutate(region_company = paste(region,company, sep = '_')) %>% 
  split(., .$region_company)

iwalk(df_list,function(df, nm){
  write_csv(df, paste0(nm,'.csv'))
})
```

Or if you simply wants to access it:

```
> df_list$`0_4`
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  region company     x region_company
   <int>   <int> <dbl> <chr>         
1      0       4  0.54 0_4           
2      0       4  1.61 0_4           
3      0       4  0.16 0_4
```